# What is wrong with this jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is some jQuery I have coded:

```
$(function () {

$('input').click(function() {

$(this).css("background", "-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(white),to(#DDD))");

)};

)};
```

I am getting a console error of syntax error at the first `)};`. I will probably bang my head against the wall for the next hour because I missed some ridiculously simple bug... but O well thats better than doing that and not finding the bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function () {

$('input').click(function() {

  $(this).css("background", "-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(white),to(#DDD))");

});

});
```

You had the parenthesis and curly braces reversed on the last 2 lines!

Comment: o wow, thanks! as I said I will be banging my head against the wall for the next hour :) .

Comment: yup, I just have to wait the 15 mins :(

Comment: @chromedude , thats why you should always use firebug..it will help you to fix these kind of issues.

Comment: @kobe the thing is I did and it told me that it was a problem there I am just stupid enough that I missed that option. :(

Answer (score 2):

There are two syntax errors:

1. Change this `)};` to this `});`, in last row
2. Change this `)};` to this `});`, in pre-last row

:)